# How to get Microsoft Access to get the file dimensions saved to a table?

Tags: vba, ms-access

How to get Microsoft Access to get the file dimensions saved to a table?
This is the code I am using. Any help you can offer on how I can pull the image file dimensions and add them to my table.

```
Sub ListFiles()
      
    Dim Counter As Integer
    
    Set myObject = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Set MySource = myObject.GetFolder("X:\I m A g E - F o L d E r\Website\Brochure Images & PDF\")
    
    On Error Resume Next
      
    DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE *FROM tblPDFs"
 
    Dim db As Database
    Dim rst As Recordset
    Dim mysql As String
    
    Set db = CurrentDb()
    mysql = "tblPDFs"
    Set rst = db.OpenRecordset(mysql, dbOpenDynaset)
      
    For Each MyFile In MySource.Files
        rst.AddNew
        rst![FilePath] = MyFile.Path
        rst![FileName] = MyFile.Name
        rst![FileDim] = MyFile.Dimensions
        rst![FileType] = MyFile.Type
        rst.Update
          
                  Counter = Counter + 1
    Next
          

    ' Clean up
    rst.Close
    db.Close
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
     
    Set myObject = Nothing
    Set MySource = Nothing
     
    MsgBox "Listed " & Counter & " Files."

      
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you try googling for a solution?  That might be a good place to start.

Comment: What happens when you run this code - error message, wrong result, nothing?

Comment: From my web search: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32465445/microsoft-access-vba-determining-image-dimensions

Comment: When I run the code it pulls the path, name and type of the file and adds them to their respective columns in the table. The dimensions column is left blank.

Comment: then comment out or delete  the line starting with  rst![FileDim]

Comment: I need to find a way for the script to pull the file Dimensions, but I can not figure out how to have it do that.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
Option Compare Database


'make sure you have tblPDFs
'just in case, in the visual basic for applications window (code window)
'On the Ribbon, use Tools-References to add a reference to the Microsoft Scripting Runtime
Sub ListFiles()
      
       Dim Counter As Integer
    Set myObject = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set MySource = myObject.GetFolder("URLofFolderwithFiles")
    
    On Error Resume Next
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False 'surpress some annoyances. comment out this line to see them
    DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE * FROM tblPDFs" 'clear table
 
    Dim db As Database
    Dim rst As Recordset
    Dim mysql As String
    
    Set db = CurrentDb()
    mysql = "tblPDFs"
    Set rst = db.OpenRecordset(mysql, dbOpenDynaset)
      
    For Each MyFile In MySource.Files
        rst.AddNew
        rst![FilePath] = MyFile.Path
        rst![FileName] = MyFile.Name
        rst![FileDim] = MyFile.Dimensions
        rst![FileType] = MyFile.Type
        rst.Update
          
                  Counter = Counter + 1
    Next
          

    ' Clean up
    DoCmd.Requery 'show updated table 'comment to see why this is needed
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
    rst.Close
    db.Close
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
     
    Set myObject = Nothing
    Set MySource = Nothing
     
    MsgBox "Listed " & Counter & " Files."

      
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for cleaning up modernizing the code.